# Solve Linear System Over Finite Field with Module

Tags: sage

Is there in sage, any instruction to solve a linear system equations
module p(x) (polynomial over finite field), where the system coefficients are polynomials over finite field in any indeterminate?. I know that for integers exists something like, example

```
sage: I6 = IntegerModRing(6)
sage: M = random_matrix(I6, 4, 4)
sage: v = random_vector(I6, 4)
sage: M \ v
(4, 0, 2, 1)
```

Here my code

```
F.<a> = GF(2^4)
PR = PolynomialRing(F,'X')
X = PR.gen()
a11 = (a^2)*(X^3)+(a^11)*(X^2)+1
a12 = (a)*(X^4)+(a^13)*(X^3)+X+1
a13 = X^2+(a^13)*(X^3)+a*(X^2)+1
a21 = X^3
a22 = X+a
a23 = X^2+X^3+a*X
a31 = (a^12)*X+a*(X^2)
a32 = (a^8)*(X^2)+X^2+X^3
a33 = a*X + (a^2)*(X^3)
M = matrix([[a11,a12,a13],[a21,a22,a23],[a31,a32,a33]])
v = vector([(a^6)*(X^14)+X^13+X,a*(X^2)+(X^3)*(a^11)+X^2+X+a^12,(a^8)*(X^7)+a*(X^2)+(a^12)*  (X^13)+X^3+X^2+X+1])
p = (a^2 + a)*X^3 + (a + 1)*X^2 + (a^2 + 1)*X + 1 # is than 6 in the firs code
```

I'm trying

```
matrix(PolynomialModRing(p),M)\vector(PolynomialModRing(p),v)
```

but **PolynomialModRing** not exist ...

EDIT

another person talk me that I will make

```
R.<Xbar> = PR.quotient(PR.ideal(p))
# change your formulas to Xbar instead of X
A \ b
# ==> (a^3 + a, a^2, (a^3 + a^2)*Xbar^2 + (a + 1)*Xbar + a^3 + a)
```

this work fine but Now I'm trying to apply the Chinese Theorem Remainder after the code, then .... I defined

```
q = X^18 + a*X^15 + a*X^12 + X^11 + (a + 1)*X^2 + a
r = a^3*X^3 + (a^3 + a^2 + a)*X^2 + (a^2 + 1)*X + a^3 + a^2 + a
#p,q and r are relatively prime
```

and I'm trying ...

```
crt([(A\b)[0],(A\b)[1],(A\b)[2]],[p,q,r])
```

but I get

File "element.pyx", line 344, in sage.structure.element.Element.**getattr** (sage/structure/element.c:3871)
  File "misc.pyx", line 251, in sage.structure.misc.getattr_from_other_class (sage/structure/misc.c:1606)
AttributeError: 'PolynomialQuotientRing_field_with_category.element_class' object has no attribute 'quo_rem'

I'm thinking that problem is the change Xbar to X

Here my complete example to integers

```
from numpy import arange, eye, linalg
#2x-3y+2z=21
#x+4y-z=1
#-x+2y+z=17
A = matrix([[2,-3,2],[1,4,-1],[-1,2,1]])
b=vector([21,1,17])
p=[17,11,13]
d=det(A)
dlist=[0,0,0]
ylist=matrix(IntegerModRing(p[i]),[[2,-3,2],[1,4,-1], [-1,2,1]])\vector(IntegerModRing(p[i]),[21,1,17])
p1=[int(ylist[0]),int(ylist[1]),int(ylist[2])]
CRT(p1,p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... this is what you want?  Continuing your example:

```
G = F.extension(p)   # This is what you want for "PolynomialModRing(p)
matrix(G,M)\vector(G,v)
```

which outputs

```
(a^3 + a, a^2, (a^3 + a^2)*X^2 + (a + 1)*X + a^3 + a)
```

In your question you ask "where the system coefficients are polynomials over finite field in any indeterminate" so what I'm doing above is *NOT* what you have actually asked, which would be a weird question to ask given your example. So, I'm going to just try to read your mind... :-)

Comment: What's the mistake in  "where the system coefficients are polynomials over finite field in any indeterminate"?